# Jmeter sudden increase of response times at distributed mode

Tags: time, jmeter, timeout, response

[image: screenshot]

Hi all,

Even if with small users (e.g. total 1000) in distributed mode, I have a sudden increase in response times through the end of the test distorting the result. For ones with high response times, Jmeter throws "Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException/Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect" error. All my machines (18 slaves 1 master) are Windows.

At what point I make mistake? Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

How many users you have in [Thread Group(s)](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)?

In order to get 1000 users with 18 slave machines you should have 55 threads (virtual users) in all Thread Groups.

If you have 1000 users defined in the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) and have 18 slave machines - you're kicking off **18000 threads** which might be too much for your application.

You can check how many exactly virtual users were active at the given moment of your test execution using [Active Threads Over Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener (the listener can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/))

Comment: Hi, thank you for help. I have 55 threads per slave. In total 1000 users are available for the test. Still I could not figure out why through the end of the test I have such high response times. I run a non-gui distributed test with listeners are disabled, and without retrieving embedded resources.